# Test rendering template specified number of times

Tags: testing, partial-views, rspec-rails

Cart has several cart items.

How to test, whether "cart_item" template was rendered for each item, presented in cart?

In other words, how to test, whether template was rendered specified number of times?

I need something like this:

```
it "renders cart_items" do
  render
  rendered.should render_template("checkout/cart/_cart_item", :times => cart.cart_items.count)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The rspec-rails documentation seems to cover your test-case: http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/file/README.md#View_specs

For reasons of completeness here a copy-paste of the specific part from the documentation:

```
describe "events/index" do
  it "renders _event partial for each event" do
    assign(:events, [stub_model(Event), stub_model(Event)])
    render
    view.should render_template(:partial => "_event", :count => 2)
  end
end
```